# Excel 2007 VBA code to automate extracting and storing numeric values from a string with special characters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string which is in A1 of Sheet1 and it refreshes regularly.
it looks like this -
{"rows":[{"advances":637,"declines":836,"unchanged":76,"total":1549}],"success":"true","results":1}

I want to extract numeric values 637 and 836 and 76 and store it in separate columns. The values keeps on changing, like 637 can be sometimes 1200.
I want a VBA code, not an user defined function to automatically extract the numeric data and store it.

I am using this code, but I am not getting anything. What is wrong?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
Dim s As String
Dim fieldNames As Variant
Dim iField As Long
Dim nFields As Long
Dim v As Variant

' specify what you want
fieldNames = Array("advances", "declines", "unchanged")
nFields = UBound(fieldNames) - LBound(fieldNames) + 1

s = [a1].Value ' read in the string

' parse it, put values in a Variant array
ReDim v(1 To 1, 1 To nFields)
For iField = 1 To nFields
s = Mid(s, InStr(s, """" & fieldNames(iField - 1) & """:") _
    + Len(fieldNames(iField - 1)) + 3)
v(1, iField) = Left(s, InStr(s, ",") - 1)
Next iField

' write array to sheet
[b1].Resize(1, nFields).Value = v
End If
Range("=Sheet1!$E$1:$G$1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Updated").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)      
Sheets("Updated").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your text JSON?  There are a few methods out there for parsing JSON with VBA.

Comment: why the first three numbers but not the 1549 and ? Are there always at least three numbers stored next to advances, declines and unchanged? And a user defined function is VBA - you may be confusing a UDF with a normal excel function

Comment: @Tim Williams, thanks a lot, yes it is JSON indeed.

Comment: @brettdj, I need only first three numbers, the total value is not required.As far as storing numbers in the string is concerned, as the data is refreshed by the web query automatically, it changes, it can 1/2/3/4 digits.thanks alot sir.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett, thanks a lot sir.Yes I want a VBA sub to run automatically.

Comment: Are you using a web query? If so you can run a VBA event automatically when your query refresh finishes

Comment: @brettdj, am using web query to refresh the data, but I am giving the link to download my excel sheet.please hv a look whether your code works in it?please.  the link - http://ifile.it/xjr28nq

Comment: Yes - my formulae on Sheet1 update correctly as is if A1 is blank and is then refreshed

Comment: @brettdj, it gets the values, now I want those values to be copied to another sheet, only values not the formula, and give a time stamp to it, how to do it please.

Comment: I have added a sheet event to my code which replaces your current sheet event

Comment: @brettdj, ,please post the code of added sheet event, I am a novice, please help, its showing error if am copying it as it is.by the way will it be pasted inside your function in the module or on the sheet1

Comment: See my post with code - the sheet event has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would be tempted to use standard functions for this you could run a VBA UDF like so

to get the first match from A1 (as a number)

```
=RegexMatches(A1,1)
```

the second match

```
=RegexMatches(A1,2)
```

and so on

The UDF returns "No Match" where no matches are found, or a message "Less than X matches" if you try to extract a match from a position that doesb't exist

[image]

```
Function RegexMatches(strIn As String, LngPos As Long)
    Dim objRegex
    Dim objRegexMC
    Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With objRegex
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = ":(\d+),"
        If .test(strIn) Then
            Set objRegexMC = .Execute(strIn)
            If objRegexMC.Count >= LngPos Then
                RegexMatches = CLng(objRegexMC(LngPos - 1).submatches(0))
            Else
                RegexMatches = "Less than " & LngPos & " matches"
            End If
        Else
            RegexMatches = "No Match"
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[Update: added sheet event code]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("Updated").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
'set row1 as first row if it is blank
If rng1.Row = 2 And rng1.Offset(-1, 0) = vbNullString Then Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(-1, 0)
rng1.Resize(1, 3).Value = Range("B1:D1").Value
rng1.Offset(0, -1).Value = Now
End Sub
```

Comment: how to automate it? the data refreshes every 1 minute.and also I need to use the data to another sheet with a time stamp, so that I can get a time series chart.Now there is problem while copying the extracted values to another sheet, that is I am not getting anything.:(

Comment: ,please post the code of added sheet event, I am a novice, please help, its showing error if am copying it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an instance of the windows script control to parse the text for you:

```
Sub Tester()

Dim JSON As String

Dim sc As Object

    JSON = "{""rows"":[{""advances"":637,""declines"":836," & _
             """unchanged"":76,""total"":1549}]" & _
             ",""success"":""true"",""results"":1}"

    'JSON = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value    

    Set sc = CreateObject("ScriptControl")
    sc.Language = "JScript"

    sc.Eval "var o = eval(" & JSON & ")" 'evaluate to an object

    Debug.Print "success", sc.Eval("o.success")
    Debug.Print "#results", sc.Eval("o.results")

    Debug.Print "  advances", sc.Eval("o.rows[0].advances")
    Debug.Print "  declines", sc.Eval("o.rows[0].declines")
    Debug.Print "  unchanged", sc.Eval("o.rows[0].unchanged")

End Sub
```

Comment: I copied your code and inserted as a module and tried to run, but it is not returning anything.Am I missing something or what?any help appreciated.

Comment: It just prints to the Immediate window in the vb editor.  Press Ctrl+G to bring that up.  You'll have to modify it to put the extracted values where you want them.  Plenty of examples out there for that...

Answer (score 1):

I needed something similar and developed the following code. I have no doubts that it could be made more sophisticated but it provided me with the required result.

```
Dim cr_ref As String                ' Original reference - alpha and numer
Dim new_ref As String               ' Resultant numeirc only reference
Dim iAsciiCode As Integer
Dim sCount As Integer               ' Length of reference

cr_ref = Trim(Cells(4, 19).Value)       ' Get reference from source
sCount = Len(cr_ref)
new_ref = ""                ' Start with empty result
    For i = 0 To sCount - 1                              ' Strip out all except digits
        iAsciiCode = Asc(Mid(cr_ref, i + 1, 1)) ' Give me Ascii code
        If iAsciiCode >= 48 And iAsciiCode <= 57 Then   ' I only want 0-9
            new_ref = new_ref & Mid(cr_ref, i + 1, 1)   ' Append numeric digit
        End If
    Next i

' Result is in new_ref
```

Comment: Oops - didn't read the question. Since there are multiple values, include the delimiter (, or :) in the strip search and then use the result to eke out each number.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
Dim s As String
Dim fieldNames As Variant
Dim iField As Long
Dim nFields As Long
Dim v As Variant

' specify what you want
fieldNames = Array("advances", "declines", "unchanged")
nFields = UBound(fieldNames) - LBound(fieldNames) + 1

s = [a1].Value ' read in the string

' parse it, put values in a Variant array
ReDim v(1 To 1, 1 To nFields)
For iField = 1 To nFields
    s = Mid(s, InStr(s, """" & fieldNames(iField - 1) & """:") _
        + Len(fieldNames(iField - 1)) + 3)
    v(1, iField) = Left(s, InStr(s, ",") - 1)
Next iField

' write array to sheet
[b1].Resize(1, nFields).Value = v
```

Comment: Corbett, your code I copied and created a module and pasted there, it works but not automatically, everytime I have to press run from the VB editor to run the code, how to automate it, since I am trying to copy the values and create a chart out of it.please help.

Comment: The code is not updating  when the new values are refreshed automatically, please help.I am uploading the file, please see what is wrong.warm regards.i want the code to retrieve values automatically from the string everytime its refreshed.the link - http://ifile.it/21nc67u/Book1.xlsm

Comment: suppose I want to call your macro to start after auto refresh is done every 1 minute, what would be the code?